# FF 3+ addon: Page request with current cookies

Tags: http, firefox-addon, request

Following the recipe on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_Sandboxed_HTTP_Connections) works fine, except it can't doesn't show how to use the cookies already stored on the browser (for instance: if you are already logged in Twitter, www.twitter.com will show your user's page, not twitter's front page).

Which made me wonder: is there a simpler way to make simple GET requests from a Firefox (3+) addon, which also use the current cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer over here: [Reading web-page cookies from a Firefox extension (XUL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523137/reading-web-page-cookies-from-a-firefox-extension-xul)

Comment: Thanks, but that is what I am trying to avoid. The request for cookie aware request is more complex. Not a lot, but many simple things can get quite complex.